# SQL TRIGGER handling multiple INSERTED rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an `UPDATE` which looks like this:

```
UPDATE STOR SET
    STOR.BLOC1 = T.BLOC1,
    STOR.BLOC2 = T.BLOC2,
    STOR.BLOC3 = T.BLOC3
FROM BLDG B INNER JOIN STOR S
ON S.B_ID = B.B_ID
CROSS APPLY dbo.INVENTORIZE(B.B_ID) AS T;
```

And a `TRIGGER` which is meant to insert a row (like a log) for each update above.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgrCYCLE
ON STOR
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @BLDG int, @ACT varchar(4), @QTY decimal(3,1);

SET @BLDG = (SELECT B_ID FROM inserted)
SET @QTY= (SELECT BLOC1 FROM inserted)
SET @ACT = CASE WHEN @QTY < 0 THEN 'SELL'
            ELSE 'BUY' END

INSERT INTO INVT VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @BLDG, @ACT, @QTY)
```

I have two problems for which I need assistance:

1. the fact of the `inserted` pseudo table having multiple rows is returning an error ("Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."). I haven't been able to transport answers in similar questions to my case.
2. how to have the trigger work for ***n*** number of BLOC columns (BLOC1, BLOC2, BLOC3, BLOCn...)

Comment: You need to better define 2. What does "work for n number of BLOC columns" mean? Are there multiple columns in the destination table? Are you trying to insert a new row per BLOC column? Right now the requirement is very loosy-goosy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, you can't use variables to store values from multiple rows. Insert as a set.

```
INSERT dbo.INVT -- schema prefix!
  (column_list!!!)
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, B_ID, 
    CASE WHEN BLOC1 < 0 THEN 'SELL' ELSE 'BUY' END, BLOC1
  FROM inserted;
```

For the second question, the easiest way is probably an INSERT statement per BLOCn.

```
INSERT dbo.INVT -- schema prefix!
  (column_list!!!)
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, B_ID, 
    CASE WHEN BLOC2 < 0 THEN 'SELL' ELSE 'BUY' END, BLOC2
  FROM inserted;

INSERT dbo.INVT -- schema prefix!
  (column_list!!!)
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, B_ID, 
    CASE WHEN BLOC3 < 0 THEN 'SELL' ELSE 'BUY' END, BLOC3
  FROM inserted;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Aaron's got really quick fingers  :-)

Comment: Thx! the `UPDATE` has several `BLOC` columns and `INVT` needs to hold a record for each, e.g. an insert for each BLOC for each inserted

Comment: Follow-up: when the BLOCn value is 0 or null, it shouldn't INSERT into INVT. I tried this `IF ISNULL((SELECT BLOC2 FROM inserted),0) > 0 BEGIN ... END` but no luck.

Comment: @greener uh, just add `WHERE COALESCE(BLOC2,0) <> 0`